# Square board problem with recurrence relations

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

*(Reference: Probability - An Introduction, Grimmett & Welsh, Exercise 1.11.13 p.21)*

> A square board is divided into 16 equal squares by lines drawn parallel to  its sides. A counter is placed at random on one of these squares and is then moved $n$ times. At each of these moves, it can be transferred to any neighbouring square, horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, all such moves being equally likely.
>
> Let $c_n$ be the probability that a particular corner site is occupied after $n$ such independent moves, and let the corresponding probabilities for an intermediate site at the side of the board and for a site in the middle of the board be $s_n$ and $m_n$, respectively. Show that
> $$4c_n+8s_n+4m_n=1$$and that $$c_n=\tfrac25s_{n-1}+\tfrac18 m_{n-1}$$
> Find two other relations for $s_n$ and $m_n$ in terms of $c_{n-1}$, $s_{n-1}$, $m_{n-1}$ and hence find $c_n$, $s_n$ and $m_n$.

I have a stupid question. I think I overlook something, but I can't seem to get it.

The square board looks like this:
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline C&S&S&C \\\hline S&M&M&S\\\hline S&M&M&S\\\hline C&S&S&C \\\hline\end{array}$.

The first condition is trivial, but for the probability of $c_n$ I get $c_n=\frac{\color{red}1}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{8}m_{n-1}$. Why is that not correct? From $S$ I have 5 moves, 1 of which is to go to $C$.

Also, my transition matrix becomes

$$\begin{bmatrix}c_n \\ s_n \\ m_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{\color{red}1}{5} & \frac18 \\ \frac23 & \frac25 & \frac12 \\ \frac13 & \frac25 & \frac38\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c_{n-1}\\s_{n-1}\\m_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$
in which case it would be weird to have $\frac{2}{5}$, because then it wouldn't add up to 1 anymore.

Comment: I'm with you, I see $\frac 15$ here.  I think I have a copy of their book somewhere, I'll look it up.

Comment: Are you sure of your reference?  I'm looking at Grimmett and Stirzaker, and their chapter one problems only go up to $1.8.x$.

Comment: Yes, but it's the other Probability book from Grimmett, namely Probability An Introduction 2nd by Grimmett and Welsh.

Comment: Ah, that one I don't have.  Still, I'm with you on the $\frac 15$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're logic is fine, but you're reading the question in the wrong way: $c_n$, $m_n$ and $s_n$ are not the probabilities that *a* corner, middle or intermediate site is occupied, it is the probaility that *a particular* corner, middle or intermediate is occupied. Therefore, we don't have $c_n+m_n+s_n=1$, but we get that $4c_n+4m_n+8s_n=1$, just like is stated in this question.

To see that you're solution does not yield the right solution, assume that $4c_{n-1}+4m_{n-1}+8s_{n-1}=1$, and plug in $c_{n-1}$, $m_{n-1}$ and $s_{n-1}$ in the difference equations you give in your matrix. I am now going to calculate $4c_n+4m_n+8s_n$, and show this is unequal to 1, given $4c_{n-1}+4m_{n-1}+8s_{n-1}=1$:

\begin{eqnarray}
4c_n+4m_n+8s_n & = &  4\left(\frac{1}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{8}m_{n-1}\right)+4\left(\frac{2}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{3}{8}m_{n-1}+\frac{1}{3}c_{n-1}\right) \\& + & 8\left(\frac{2}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{3}{8}m_{n-1}+\frac{1}{3}c_{n-1}\right)\\
& = & \frac{28}{5}s_{n-1}+6m_{n-1}+\frac{20}{3}c_{n-1}\\
& \neq &1.
\end{eqnarray}

The correct method is, like instructed, interpret $c_n$, $m_n$ and $s_n$ as probalities of being in a particular corner, middle and intermediate site, respectively. Because of symmetry of the game, $c_n$, $m_n$ and $s_n$ have to be the same for all corner, middle and intermediate sites, respectively. We proceed as follows:

1. Each corner site has three adjacent sites: two intermediate and and middle. When we are in an intermediate site at time $n-1$, we have probability of $\frac{1}{5}$ of going to a corner site, because only one out of the five adjacent sites of the intermediate site is a corner sites. We have to multiply by $2s_{n-1}$ because each corner site has two adjacent intermediate sites and $s_{n-1}$ is the probability of being in a particular intermediate site one period earlier. Similarly, each corner site has one adjacent middle site, and each middle site has eight adjacent sites, one of which is a corner site. Again, we have to multiply by the probability of being at a middle site at time $n-1$: $m_{n-1}$. So we obtain the first difference equation: $c_n=\frac{2}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{8}m_{n-1}$.
2. The second and third difference equation are obtained using exactly the same logic as for the first one. Check as an exercise the second and third difference equation: $m_n=\frac{4}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{3}{8}m_{n-1}+\frac{1}{3}c_{n-1}$.
3. $s_n=\frac{2}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{2}{8}m_{n-1}+\frac{1}{3}c_{n-1}$

Thus, I obtain the following transition matrix.

$$\begin{bmatrix}s_n \\ m_n \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac25 & \frac14 & \frac13\\ \frac45 & \frac38 & \frac13 \\ \frac25 & \frac18 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}s_{n-1}\\m_{n-1}\\c_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}=M\begin{bmatrix}s_{n-1}\\m_{n-1}\\c_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

You can check that using these difference equations, the condition $4c_n+4m_n+8s_n=1$ is fullfilled given that is is fullfilled at $t=1$, and therefore respect the fact that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$, contrary to your difference equations:

\begin{eqnarray}
4c_n+4m_n+8s_n & = &  4\left(\frac{2}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{8}m_{n-1}\right)+4\left(\frac{4}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{3}{8}m_{n-1}+\frac{1}{3}c_{n-1}\right) \\& + & 8\left(\frac{2}{5}s_{n-1}+\frac{2}{8}m_{n-1}+\frac{1}{3}c_{n-1}\right)\\
& = & 4c_{n-1}+4m_{n-1}+8s_{n-1}=1.
\end{eqnarray}

Because initially, at $t=0$, we randomly select one out of the $16$ squares, we have that
\begin{equation} \vec{x_n}=\left( \begin{array}{c} s_n \\ m_n \\ c_n \end{array}\right)=M^n\vec{x_0}=M^n\left( \begin{array}{c} \frac{1}{16} \\ \frac{1}{16} \\ \frac{1}{16} \end{array}\right).
\end{equation}

To calculate $M^n$ efficiently, we are going to diagonalize the matrix to obtain an equation of the form

$$\vec{x_n}=c_1\vec{v_1}\lambda_1^n+c_2\vec{v_2}\lambda_2^n+c_3\vec{v_3}\lambda_3^n, $$
hoping there are three distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_i^n$ with corresponding eigenvectors $\vec{v_i}$ and constants $c_i$. Solving this yields $\lambda_1=0$, $\lambda_2=-\frac{9}{40}$ and $\lambda_3=1$, with corresponding eigenvectors:

$$\vec{v_1}=\left( \begin{array}{c} -5 \\ 16 \\ -6 \end{array}\right);\vec{v_2}=\left( \begin{array}{c} -2 \\ 1 \\ 3 \end{array}\right);\vec{v_3}=\left( \begin{array}{c} 5 \\ 8 \\ 3 \end{array}\right).$$

Now we plug in the initial conditions $\vec{x_0}$ and $\vec{x_1}$ and solve for the constants $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ and we find $c_1=-\frac{1}{432}$, $c_2=\frac{13}{3024}$ and $c_3=\frac{1}{84}$. Thus we obtain the following expression for $\vec{x_n}$, using the convention $0^0=1$, valid $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$:

$$\vec{x_n}=c_1\vec{v_1}\lambda_1^n+c_2\vec{v_2}\lambda_2^n+c_3\vec{v_3}\lambda_3^n=-\frac{1}{432}\left( \begin{array}{c} -5 \\ 16 \\ -6 \end{array}\right)0^n+\frac{13}{3024}\left( \begin{array}{c} -2 \\ 1 \\ 3 \end{array}\right)(-\frac{9}{40})^n+\frac{1}{84}\left( \begin{array}{c} 5 \\ 8 \\ 3 \end{array}\right).$$

I hope this helps you.